# Squashing memory leak caused by using CGPathCreateCopyByTransforming and CGPathCreateCopy

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I'm using ARC and a while loop to adjust several CGPathRefs until they fit within some constraints I have, and I need access to the paths once the conditions of the while loop are satisfied.

Can someone explain how my code is leaking?

The documentation for the CGCreateCopy... functions say they create a new copy, which you are responsible for releasing.  So I believe my code path (the end of the while loop) does release the path references which Instruments is catching and attributing leaked objects to.

The Instrument call outs are denoted in the code below with comments right below the place Instruments was highlighting.

This routine is given a GCSize size that is the size of a rectangle and an int value which is a numerical value that eventually will be shown within the shape created here (dimensions of the shape are somewhat dependent upon the size of the string representation of this value)

I should note that the code does produce the required paths exactly as I want -- I'm not asking anyone to debug this block!  But it leaks and I don't understand why.

```
float lineThickness = size.width;
float perimeterStrokeWidth = lineThickness * 2;
CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake( perimeterStrokeWidth / 1.5, perimeterStrokeWidth * 1.25 );
float shadowBlur = perimeterStrokeWidth * 2.0;

NSString *edgeSymbol = @"°";
CGPathRef rightEdgePath = NULL;
CGPathRef leftEdgePath = NULL;
CGPathRef valueStringPath = NULL;
CGAffineTransform adjust, flip;
float pointsize, deltaX, deltaY, inset, pointSizeThatFits;
CGRect valueRect, edgeRect, leftEdgeRect, rectForValue;

CGSize trialSize = size;
pointsize = size.height;
CGPoint tdc; // top dead center
CGPoint bdc; // bottom dead center

NSLog(@"\n\n");
BOOL done = false;
int attempts = 0;
int attemptsRemaining = 11; // ensure no infinite looping

while ( ! done ) {
    done = YES; // presumptive close!  tests below will reset if they fail
    --attemptsRemaining;

    trialSize = CGSizeMake(trialSize.width, trialSize.height - attempts);
    ++attempts;

    lineThickness = trialSize.height / 60;
    perimeterStrokeWidth = lineThickness * 2;
    shadowOffset = CGSizeMake( perimeterStrokeWidth / 1.5, perimeterStrokeWidth * 1.0 );
    shadowBlur = perimeterStrokeWidth * 2.0;

    pointsize = [UIFont sizeFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Alameda"
                                                 size:pointsize]
                       toFitText:edgeSymbol
                      withinRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                            0,
                                            trialSize.width,
                                            trialSize.height)];
    // sizeFont:toFitText:withinRect: is a custom addition to UIFont that
    // recursively tries smaller and smaller pointsize values until the
    // text fits within the rectangle provided.

    CGPathRef tmpRightEdgePath = [edgeSymbol newPathWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Alameda" size:trialSize.height * 1.1]];
    // newPathWithFont: is a custom addition to NSString that returns a 
    // CGPathRef representing the glyphs that make up the string, rendered in
    // the font (and size) specified

    flip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);

    CGPathRef tmpLeftEdgePath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(tmpRightEdgePath, &flip);

    edgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpRightEdgePath);

    // Center the symbol vertically in the size we were given (maybe up a little because of the shadow below?)

    deltaY = ( (size.height / 2) - (edgeRect.size.height / 2) - edgeRect.origin.y);

    // Slide it over to the right edge, inset slightly for the shadow
    inset = shadowOffset.width + shadowBlur;
    deltaX = ( trialSize.width - edgeRect.origin.x - edgeRect.size.width - inset);

    adjust = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY);
    CGPathRef tmpRightEdgePath1 = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(tmpRightEdgePath, &adjust);
    CGPathRelease(tmpRightEdgePath);
    tmpRightEdgePath = NULL;
    edgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpRightEdgePath1);

    leftEdgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpLeftEdgePath);
    deltaX = inset - leftEdgeRect.origin.x;
    adjust = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY);
    CGPathRef tmpLeftEdgePath1 = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(tmpLeftEdgePath, &adjust);
    CGPathRelease(tmpLeftEdgePath);
    tmpLeftEdgePath = NULL;

    leftEdgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpLeftEdgePath1);

    rectForValue = CGRectMake(leftEdgeRect.origin.x + leftEdgeRect.size.width,
                                     leftEdgeRect.origin.y,
                                     edgeRect.origin.x - leftEdgeRect.origin.x - leftEdgeRect.size.width,
                                     leftEdgeRect.size.height);

    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value];
    pointSizeThatFits = [UIFont sizeFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:trialSize.height]
                               toFitText:valueString
                              withinRect:rectForValue];
    valueStringPath = [valueString newPathWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:pointSizeThatFits]];

    valueRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(valueStringPath);
    deltaY = ( (size.height / 2) - (valueRect.size.height / 2) - valueRect.origin.y);
    deltaX = ( (trialSize.width / 2)  - (valueRect.size.width / 2)  - valueRect.origin.x);
    adjust = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaX, deltaY);
    CGPathRef tmpValueStringPath1 = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(valueStringPath, &adjust);
    CGPathRelease(valueStringPath);
    valueStringPath = NULL;

    valueRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpValueStringPath1);

    CGPathRef tmpRightEdgePath2;
    CGPathRef tmpLeftEdgePath2;

    if ((valueRect.origin.x + valueRect.size.width) < edgeRect.origin.x) {
        float gapToClose = edgeRect.origin.x - (valueRect.origin.x + valueRect.size.width);
        adjust = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(- gapToClose, 0);
        {
            tmpRightEdgePath2 = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(tmpRightEdgePath1, &adjust);
            // ^^^^ Instruments reports 5.9% of leaks here
            CGPathRelease(tmpRightEdgePath1);
            tmpRightEdgePath1 = NULL;
        }

        adjust = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(gapToClose, 0);
        {
            tmpLeftEdgePath2 = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(tmpLeftEdgePath1, &adjust);
            // ^^^^ Instruments reports 23.5% of leaks here
            CGPathRelease(tmpLeftEdgePath1);
            tmpLeftEdgePath1 = NULL;
        }

        leftEdgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpLeftEdgePath2);
    } else {
        {
            tmpRightEdgePath2 = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpRightEdgePath1);
            CGPathRelease(tmpRightEdgePath1);
            tmpRightEdgePath1 = NULL;
        }
        {
            tmpLeftEdgePath2  = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpLeftEdgePath1);
            CGPathRelease(tmpLeftEdgePath1);
            tmpLeftEdgePath1 = NULL;
        }
        leftEdgeRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(tmpLeftEdgePath2);
    }

    tdc.x = CGRectGetMidX(rectForValue);
    bdc.x = tdc.x;

    tdc.y = leftEdgeRect.origin.y - (tdc.x - leftEdgeRect.origin.x) * 0.08; // SWAG on the 10% of width

    if ((tdc.y - lineThickness/2.0) < 0) {
        done = NO;
    }

    bdc.y = leftEdgeRect.origin.y + leftEdgeRect.size.height + (leftEdgeRect.origin.y - tdc.y);

    float shadowness = shadowOffset.height;
    if ((bdc.y + shadowness) > size.height) {
        done = NO;
    }

    if (attemptsRemaining <= 0) {
        done = YES;
    }

    // And finally, assign them out if DONE!

    if (done) {
        leftEdgePath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpLeftEdgePath2);
        // ^^^^ Instruments reports 35.3% of leaks here
        rightEdgePath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpRightEdgePath2);
        // ^^^^ Instruments reports 35.3% of leaks here
        valueStringPath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpValueStringPath1);
    }
    CGPathRelease(tmpLeftEdgePath2);
    tmpLeftEdgePath2 = NULL;
    CGPathRelease(tmpRightEdgePath2);
    tmpRightEdgePath2 = NULL;
    CGPathRelease(tmpValueStringPath1);
    tmpValueStringPath1 = NULL;
}
// what follows is the application of those paths within CGContext drawing calls.
```

I understand from the other helpful answers hereabouts on Instruments and Leaks that the flagged lines are generally where the soon-to-be-leaked object was created.  With that in mind I follow downward to see where I might be assigning a new path without first releasing the prior path, but there aren't any (that I can see -- but I'll admit I'm getting a little bleary eyed looking at this).

Comment: How about `valueStringPath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpValueStringPath1);`, are you releasing it? Same with `leftEdgePath` and `rightEdgePath`

Comment: If you were to use `UIBezierPath` instead of `CGPath`, ARC would take care of the retains and releases for you.

Comment: Thanks. I can look into that but I have a lot of subsequent code in here which walks through the generated paths using CGPathApply functions, and when I initially looked at UIBezierPath I didn't see that I could do the same thing there, but I'll go look again.

Comment: ACB, I do release valueStringPath, but after all the CGContextAddPath... CGContextStrokePath... etc. code.  valueStringPath has much less work performed on it and isn't being signaled as leaking, so I have been comparing how I work with it to the left edge and right edge paths, but they are just transformed one time more than the valueStringPath.  That's part of what's so frustrating about this!

Comment: @robmayoff -- As you might guess, I ultimately did move to using UIBezierPaths!  So thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the benefit of others who find themselves vexed by memory leak problems I'm going to provide the answer to my problem here because the sleuthing process may help you.

In the middle of the code listing you can see where I inform the compiler that I will soon be using two CGPathRefs, initially inside the scope of an if/then/else, so I needed them allocated (?) outside that block so they are local to my routine.

```
CGPathRef tmpRightEdgePath2;
CGPathRef tmpLeftEdgePath2;
```

By changing those to:

```
CGPathRef tmpRightEdgePath2 = NULL;
CGPathRef tmpLeftEdgePath2 = NULL;
```

That cleared up the two leaks being reported as occurring during the if/then/else statement.

So now my only two remaining leaks are reported inside the if (done) {} block.

In Instruments, looking at the Leaks tool, the Cycles & Roots -> Leak Cycles -> foo History I see where the 10 memory events end with a RefCt being 1, so clearly a leak:

```
#  Category           Event Type    RefCt  ResponsibleLibrary  Responsible Caller
0  NSMutableRLEArray  Malloc        1      Foundation          -[NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:attributes:]
1  NSMutableRLEArray  Release       0      Foundation          -[NSConcreteAttributedString dealloc]
2  NSMutableRLEArray  Free          0      Foundation          -[NSRLEArray dealloc]
3  CGPath             Malloc        1      CoreGraphics        CGTypeCreateInstance
4  CGPath             CFRelease     0      my app              my routine
5  CGPath             Free          0      my app              my routine
6  CGPath             Malloc        1      CoreGraphics        CGTypeCreateInstance
7  CGPath             CFRelease     0      my app              my routine
8  CGPath             Free          0      my app              my routine
9  CGPath             Malloc        1      CoreGraphics        CGTypeCreateInstance
```

So at some point after I thought I was done manipulating my paths there had to be another CGCreateCopy... style call occurring, since a Malloc was called *after* I had released everything.  So by using search/find I worked my way forward through the drawing code and found a last CGPathCreateCopyByTransforming:

```
CGAffineTransform slightUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, - lineThickness * 2 );
leftEdgePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(leftEdgePath, &slightUp);
rightEdgePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(rightEdgePath, &slightUp);
```

Which are guaranteed leaks since the retain count went up by one during that copy.  So I reworked those to be:

```
CGAffineTransform slightUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, - lineThickness * 2 );
CGMutablePathRef finalLeftEdgePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(leftEdgePath, &slightUp);
CGPathRelease(leftEdgePath);
CGMutablePathRef finalRightEdgePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(rightEdgePath, &slightUp);
CGPathRelease(rightEdgePath);
```

And then I changed my CGContextAddPath() to match the new "final" paths, and also the final release calls to release the "final" versions and I am leak free!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check if all "Create" or "CreateCopy" has corresponding release statements. For eg:, Couldn't see release statements for,

```
valueStringPath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpValueStringPath1);
leftEdgePath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpLeftEdgePath2);
rightEdgePath = CGPathCreateCopy(tmpRightEdgePath2);
```

Comment: You are right, and my bad for not mentioning where those are located - it was really late.  Those come at the end of the all the CGContext draw code when I actually am through with those paths.